# DEBUG (7): cpid: in system.log

Tags: error, log, debug, error-log

My `system.log` generates **6 Million lines** in **2 weeks** with only the date and this error:

```
DEBUG (7): cpid:
```

Why?How can I solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using the SCP extension?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the SCP extension, you should be able to find the line:

```
Mage::log("cpid: ". $cpid);
```

in the file:

```
/app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Simple.php
```

You can comment it out to prevent the log file from filling up. It doesn't appear to do anything when the extension is configured and working properly.

Comment: I found it!
Now I've commented it and I let you know if the error appears again.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a developer left some debug code in place. As @tsHunter mentions it sounds like somebody was debugging the SCP extension. This module uses cpid extensively (configurable product id). If you're lucky you can search your code for `log("cpid` or `log('cpid`. If you're unlucky the cpid is logged from a dynamic attribute and it'll be harder to find.

Comment: I found it and now I hope I'm lucky. :)